# Components go missing when refreshing or reloading a page in vaadin

Tags: java, web, vaadin, web-frameworks

I am using vaadin to make a web application.  The web application is composed of different views and one main UI page, the UI page is where the navigator is declared and the view pages are added to it.  I have a couple of different views that the navigator navigates to, and each view has a menu panel (which is not a view it is a class that I make visible once the user logs in).  Everything works fine when you navigate to the different views (you see the menu panel), but when you refresh the page (hit refresh button)  the menu panel disappears.

I am thinking it is caused by the navigator because it is the only thing that is controlling the navigation between different views, but have not figured out exactly what is the problem

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Comment: I tried to but there is thousands of lines of code in different files, so I was did not know what to put.  Do you have anything specific you want to see?

Comment: I posted the solution to preserving on refresh, do you know how to preserve on leaving the site and coming back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To preserve the application on a refresh you add the @PreserveOnRefresh annotation to the main UI file.